# How to put html tag around word in string

Tags: php, laravel

I need to identify a word in the string and then add the tag "< strong >word< /strong > " around the word. It turns out that there are Words that start with an uppercase or lowercase letter, so I need to identify both cases and print the result with the  tag around the word.

My code is like this:

```
@foreach($versiculos as $v)
            
           <p>{{ $v->palavra }} </p>

@endforeach
```

my controller:

```
public function palavras(Request $request, $palavra = null)
{
    
        
        $getpalavra = palavras_br::where('slug', $palavra)->first();

        $versiculos = nvi::where('palavra', 'RLIKE','[[:<:]]'.$getpalavra->palavras.'[[:>:]]')->paginate(20);
        
        return view('palavra', compact(['versiculos','getpalavra']));

    }
```

Example:

string: "Adão teve relações com Eva, sua mulher, e ela engravidou e deu à luz Caim. Disse ela: "Com o auxílio do Senhor tive um filho homem".

I need to take the word "filho" and replace it with "< strong >filho< / strong >

But I need to keep the word the way it is, because it can appear with upper or lower case "filho" or "Filho" . And in both cases I need to wrap them by the < strong > tag.

How can I identify the word and add the  tags around the word I need??

Comment: How do you know what is the word to look for in the string? ... might be good to add sample data.

Comment: Sorry, I know what the word is from the $getpalavra variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how this fits into your controller, but check preg_replace https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Without giving the full answer (best if you work it out for yourself, then you know for next time) here are some hints:

- The pattern will be '[WordBreak]word[WordBreak]'
- You need "case insensitive"
- In order to keep the case the same, you need to use "back references"
  (all described in the manual)

Start by getting the replace to work without the back reference (so "Hello" may get replaced by "hello") and then build the back reference in as a second step.

Other note: PHP has classes for manipulating HTML, but probably not going to help you in this particular case.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's definitely a good answer. But I'm a beginner and regex is still very confusing for me.

Comment: Your (and my) friend: https://regex101.com/ - been doing regex for a long, long time, but still hit this site up. Start simple: `preg_replace('/s/', '$')` to replace all your "s" with a "$", than make it case insensitive, then add the "word break", then add the back references. You WILL thank yourself for doing it, and it's easy step-by-step like this.

Comment: I solved it this way: https://prnt.sc/w-O86cZTenmf

It doesn't look the prettiest to me, but it's working... hehe thank you

Comment: Awesome - perfect start. To make a little better, add the wordbreaks (\b) before and after. You can then use "i" to make case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll polish it to make it better :)